# Convert date to unix timestamp in AIX

Tags: perl, unix, awk, aix

I have few dates which are converted like that year month & date:

```
20151213 20151214
```

In AIX seems `date -d` not recognize -d option

```
date -d 20151213 +%s
```

So I'm not able to convert that specific date format which I receive dynamically to Unix time stamp.
How to convert those dates in AIX to timestamp?

Comment: Are you looking for an answer in Perl, or anything that can be used from the shell?

Comment: What that I found perl which convert timestamp to date so I guess there is a possible way to reverse the process, just don't know how to do it ...
`perl -MPOSIX=strftime -e 'print strftime("%Y-%m-%d %T", localtime($ARGV[0])), "\n"' 1381260225`

Comment: Look at `strptime` from `Time::Piece`, it'll work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perl's [`Time::Local` module](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Local.html) is what you need:

```perl
perl -e '
    use Time::Local;
    for $d ("20151213", "20151214") {
        ($year, $month, $day) = $d =~ /(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})/;
        $epoch = timelocal(0,0,0, $day, $month-1, $year-1900);
        print "$d => $epoch\n"
    }
'
```

```
20151213 => 1449982800
20151214 => 1450069200
```

In a shell script, I'd write

```
epoch() {
    echo "$1" | perl -MTime::Local -lne '
        ($year, $month, $day) = /(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})/;
        print timelocal(0, 0, 0, $day, $month-1, $year-1900)
    '
}

timestamp=$(epoch 20151213)
```

Comment: `perl -MPOSIX=strftime -e 'for $i ("20151213", "20151214") { ($year, $month, $day) = $i =~ /(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})/; print strftime("%s\n", 0, 0, 0, $day, $month-1, $year-1900) }'`

Comment: @CorexCain: If you think you have a solution then you should post it as one. Especially don't post code in comments if you can avoid it as it is unreadable

Comment: @glennjackman: It is best to use UTC when converting timestamps. It's not helpful for your program to produce different results depending on where it is run

Comment: OK, we can use the `timegm` function instead of `timelocal`, and we get the same timestamps as your solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Perl with the [`Time::Piece`](http://metacpan.org/module/Time::Piece) module to do this concisely

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

use Time::Piece;

for ( qw/ 20151213 20151214 / ) {
    my $time = Time::Piece->strptime($_, '%Y%m%d')->epoch;
    say $time;
}
```

### output

```
1449964800
1450051200
```